# Bookmarklet requiring a space is corrupted in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarklet

Quite a while ago I created a bookmarklet to save time when opening a trac ticket. It looks like this (with the URL portion replaced with trac.example.com/example:

```
javascript:(function(){var nbr=prompt('ticket','number');f='https://trac.example.com/example/ticket/'+nbr;if(!isNaN(nbr)&&nbr>0&&!window.open(f)){location.href=f;}})()
```

This worked well for quite a while in both Chrome and Firefox. Then they both stopped working. I discovered that the problem was the space between "var nbr". I replaced the space with %20, and the bookmarklet both in Chrome and Firefox again worked.

However recently Chrome insists on removing the %20 and replacing it with a space, and the bookmarklet does not work. The bookmarklet in Firefox continues to happily work with the %20.

I also tried using + instead of %20. But that does not work either, although it does not get turned into a space.

What can be done to have the bookmarklet work in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn’t able to reproduce the problem¹ and Chrome didn’t modify the bookmarklet. But in any event, you can **remove “`var` ” from the bookmarklet**² because you don’t have to tell JavaScript what `nbr`’s type is.³

Replace your bookmarklet’s address with:

```
javascript:(function(){nbr=prompt('ticket','number');f='https://trac.example.com/example/ticket/'+nbr;if(!isNaN(nbr)&&nbr>0&&!window.open(f)){location.href=f;}})()
```

---

1. Testing on Chrome and Safari and entering `123` opened a new window and sent me to `https://trac.example.com/example/ticket/123`. Entering nothing at all – or the default text string `number` – closed the prompt window and nothing happened.
2. `var` , including the space immediately following it. Or `var+` or `var%20`.
3. Similarly, the bookmarklet initializes `f` without declaring `var f`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I removed the var%20 from Firefox and it still works fine. However, in Chrome it still does not work. The interesting thing is that for a long time it worked in Chrome just fine.Then wondering what else Chrome might have corrupted, I copied the address from Firefox into Chrome. Now it works again in Chrome. If this sticks, I will mark this answer as the accepted answer.